# Parsing XML in VBA Revealing data

Tags: xml, vba, xml-parsing

from my research I have been able to build a function in VBA for parsing XML and exposing values as I need to.  However, there is one value that is eluding me.

```
<osgb:topographicMember>
     <osgb:TopographicArea fid='osgb1000000347753568'>
     <osgb:featureCode>10053</osgb:featureCode>
     <osgb:version>4</osgb:version>
     <osgb:versionDate>2006-03-15</osgb:versionDate>
     <osgb:theme>Land</osgb:theme>
     <osgb:calculatedAreaValue>46.099150</osgb:calculatedAreaValue>
     <osgb:changeHistory>
         <osgb:changeDate>2001-03-09</osgb:changeDate>
         <osgb:reasonForChange>New</osgb:reasonForChange>
     </osgb:changeHistory>
     <osgb:descriptiveGroup>General Surface</osgb:descriptiveGroup>
     <osgb:descriptiveTerm>Multi Surface</osgb:descriptiveTerm>
     <osgb:make>Multiple</osgb:make>
     <osgb:physicalLevel>50</osgb:physicalLevel>
     <osgb:polygon><gml:Polygon srsName='osgb:BNG'>
     <gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>290996.130,92420.290   290998.010,92415.010 291000.000,92415.720 291005.770,92417.770 291003.890,92423.040 291000.000,92421.660 290996.130,92420.290 </gml:coordinates>
     </gml:LinearRing>
     </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
     </gml:Polygon>
     </osgb:polygon></osgb:TopographicArea>
     </osgb:topographicMember>
```

The value that I am trying to obtain is fid = 'osgb10000000347753568'

I can get and return TopographicArea  (using xChild.baseName) , but not the fid.

Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the input correctly, you need to open `TopographicArea` node and get its `Fid` attribute `.text` or `.NodeValue` properties (whichever suits best depending on the node data type) instead of node `.baseName`, i.e. you should use something like this:

```
Set XMLDOC = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
.....
Set SubNode = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("//[list of parent nodes]/topographicMember/TopographicArea/")
fid = SubNode.Attributes.Item(0).NodeValue
```

Perhaps I'm wrong with the notation, but the key point here you should use `.text` or `.NodeValue` properties. VBA Watch Window for XMLDOC added will be very helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Hi,  that got it, thanks.  However, is there any way to test if attributes exist before trying to expose item(0)?

Comment: @AdamSherratt I think you should check the `Attributes.Length` property which returns the amount on node attributes. If it equals 0 - there's no attributes. Also consider to use `getNamedItem` Method to locate attributes instead of Item(#): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Good luck!)